# Как мне проверить, есть ли число в массиве numpy? Мой метод с in не работает

Tags: python, numpy

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageColor
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time


while True:
    image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox= (549, 210, 897, 425));

    rgbArr = np.array(image);

    print(rgbArr);

    time.sleep(0.1);
    
    if {253, 106, 106} in rgbArr:
        exit();
    else:
        print('false');
```

Comment: Используйте np.isin https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html